# Strange behaviour with embedded resources

Tags: c#, .net, filenames, embedded-resource

I was struggling creating an embedded resource "Template.de-DE.html" in **Visual Studio 2013 Express**. I defined it correctly as "embedded resource" and "Do not copy".

When debugging my project, `this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` called in the same assembly as the resource file did not show this file, so I tried it with several file names:

- Template.de-DE.html
- Template.de.html
- Template.de_DE.html

Only the last file (Template.de_DE.html) showed up in `this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` results.

Is this a bug or are there restrictions for embedded resource files that I did not find?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

Files with names ending with ".de-DE.ext" seem to be compiled into `<MyLib>.resources.dll` in folder bin\de-DE.